# How to import an svn repo into a mercurial one?

Tags: svn, mercurial

I'm using the convert extension, so am not sure if it's the right tool, since:

```
hg convert svn://svn blah
```

gives:

```
svn://blah does not look like a Subversion repository
```

How do I do this, assuming that my repo doesn't have anonymous access?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a `http` URL to your subversion repository, or better yet bring the whole thing local with [svnsync](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.ref.svnsync.html) and use a `file` URL.  Here are some more details:

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ConvertExtension#More_about_Subversion_URL_and_Paths_Handling

Comment: I get `abort: error: Connection refused` when trying to do `hg convert http://svn blah`.

Comment: @Tshepang make sure your SVN repository is available through http:// first. Simple `svn list http://repo` should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [`convert` extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ConvertExtension) of Mercurial:

1. Enable convert extention; add `convert=` to the `[extensions]` section of .hgrc like this:

   > [extensions]
   >   convert=
2. Linux needs additional python bindings: `sudo apt-get install python-subversion`
3. Execute `hg convert` command

   - See `hg convert -h` for help
   - Example: `hg convert http://[svnserver]/[Project] --source-type svn [DestinationDir]` *(see note 2)*
4. Push to newly created Mercurial repository: `hg push https://[mercurialserver]/[Project]`

**note**: you can even repeat the hg convert command to include new changes made in the svn repository after the previous convert.

**note 2**: When hg convert doesn't work using `http://` or `svn://` you could first checkout the Subversion repository (or update an existing one) and convert using the local checkout; example: `hg convert [DirectoryOfLocalCheckout] --source-type svn [DestinationDir]`